# Streamlit identify remote user

Tags: python-3.x, streamlit

I run this streamlit app on a local server, which I'm using to allow users to run a few tasks. I need to associate each execution of a task with the user that requested it.

Ideally, I would get the user's IP address, as this identifies the user in my work's network. But that seems like a privacy problem for streamlit developers.

I've considered creating a login page, but that would become bothersome quickly.

Is there any recommended method to achieve this?